# How should I dynamically change a spinner's entries?

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

This question was not worded well enough to get the responses I wanted, so I am posting a new, almost completely different question.

Comment: Take seperate adapter for each spinner and work accordingly....

Comment: @suri I do have a separate adapter for each spinner, but what I need help with is basically editing these adapters when the selection of another spinner is changed.

Comment: So, you need to do spinner.clear() then add new data to the spinner and set the notifyDatasetchanged() thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally have an answer. The only way to access the spinners and adapters in another spinner's `onSelectedItemChanged` is to make them final. So I had to make 20 "`final`" adapters and use cases to set each one.

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the UI is not the object itself, from that, you can make a new instance, populate it and then link it to the view. Also consider using consecutive listviews for your application, it's cleaner, easier to mantain and more user friendly.

Comment: Okay, are you saying when an item is selected, make a new ArrayAdapter, then set the next spinner's adapter to it? Or something different? I'm not sure how to do that anyway, if I try to say anything about spinner2 in spinner1's OnItemSelectedListener, it says it's a misplaced construct. As for using listviews, it's a bit too crowded for that. The program was originally written for Windows Forms, and adapting it to an app is proving tedious.

Comment: I am very new to android, by the way. Or java in general for that matter. Mostly used to Visual basic, and no formal training.

Answer (score 0):

What you gotta do is, start with 2nd and 3rd spinner enabled state to false as their values are yet unknown, when the ItemSelected is fired for the first spinner you enable, clear and create a new adapter for the second based on the current selection and enable the second spinner ) repeat the same step for the third spinner, the here you gotta pay attention here to is, you gotta disable the third spinner if a new item is selected on the first spinner as now it's value is again unknown.

Comment: Wow.... And I thought the way I did it in Visual Basic was complicated.... I'll give it a shot!

Comment: it will be the same exact thing u had to do in visual basic, but with other names, u just catch the events using listeners, and do your stuff.